# Selection from dropdown list as well as checkboxes in PDF using pyPDF in Python

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf

I would like to use python to modify a PDF containing dropdown lists and multiple and single selection fields. The function: .updatePageFormFieldValues ​​will fill drop-down lists that have options to manually add values, but will not fill drop-down lists that only have specific options to choose from.I have no problem with regular forms.
Link do pliku [PDF](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gMt6inrfxfijZik_jU8gY8mIC-StTb9K/view?usp=sharing)

I've tried different ways, but they either break the checkboxes or don't work. Here's the code I've created so far from the information available on the forums.

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader
from PyPDF2.generic import BooleanObject, NameObject, IndirectObject

def set_need_appearances_writer(writer: PdfFileWriter):
    try:
        catalog = writer._root_object
        if "/AcroForm" not in catalog:
            writer._root_object.update({
                NameObject("/AcroForm"): IndirectObject(len(writer._objects), 0, writer)})

        need_appearances = NameObject("/NeedAppearances")
        writer._root_object["/AcroForm"][need_appearances] = BooleanObject(True)
        return writer

    except Exception as e:
        print('set_need_appearances_writer() catch : ', repr(e))
        return writer

infile = "input.pdf"
outfile = "output.pdf"

reader = PdfFileReader(open(infile, "rb"), strict=False)

fields = reader.getFields()
print(fields)

if "/AcroForm" in reader.trailer["/Root"]:
    reader.trailer["/Root"]["/AcroForm"].update(
        {NameObject("/NeedAppearances"): BooleanObject(True)})
    print(reader)

writer = PdfFileWriter()

if "/AcroForm" in writer._root_object:
    writer._root_object["/AcroForm"].update(
        {NameObject("/NeedAppearances"): BooleanObject(True)})

field_dictionary = {"Autor": "Mariusz"
                    }
writer.addPage(reader.getPage(0))
writer.updatePageFormFieldValues(writer.getPage(0), field_dictionary)

with open(outfile, "wb") as fp:
    writer.write(fp)
```

I also tried that, but even though the list is modified, after opening the PDF file, the changes can only be seen in regular forms.

```
import PyPDF2
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader
from PyPDF2.generic import BooleanObject, NameObject, IndirectObject

def set_need_appearances_writer(writer: PdfFileWriter):
    try:
        catalog = writer._root_object
        if "/AcroForm" not in catalog:
            writer._root_object.update({
                NameObject("/AcroForm"): IndirectObject(len(writer._objects), 0, writer)
            })

        need_appearances = NameObject("/NeedAppearances")
        writer._root_object["/AcroForm"][need_appearances] = BooleanObject(True)
        return writer

    except Exception as e:
        print('set_need_appearances_writer() catch : ', repr(e))
        return writer

with open('Raport.pdf', 'rb') as input_pdf:
    reader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(input_pdf)
    writer = PyPDF2.PdfFileWriter()
    set_need_appearances_writer(writer)

    for page_num in range(reader.getNumPages()):
        page = reader.getPage(page_num)

        if '/Annots' in page:
            for annot in page['/Annots']:
                writer_annot = annot.getObject()
                print(writer_annot)
                try:
                    if writer_annot['/Type'] == '/Annot' and writer_annot['/Subtype'] == '/Widget' and writer_annot['/T']== 'Rozpoczęcie pracy (data, godz)PW':
                        writer_annot[PyPDF2.generic.NameObject("/V")] = PyPDF2.generic.TextStringObject('1-02-2023\r12:00')
                        print(writer_annot)
                except:
                    continue
        writer.addPage(page)

    with open('output.pdf', 'wb') as output_pdf:
        writer.write(output_pdf)
```